# ListPicker System.InvalidCastException When accessing a binding object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listpicker

Here is the code XAML:

Here is the C#:
                textDefault.Text = "Selected Item is " + ((Items)this.listPicker.SelectedItem).Name;

Comment: `... + ((Items)this.listPicker.SelectedItem).Name.ToString();` ?

Comment: Sorry gents if this is unclear. Sajeetharan has sorted me out and listpicker works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast it to your Class which you bind,

something like this,

```
ClassType =  (ClassType)listPicker.SelectedItem;
if(ClassType != null)
{
textDefault.Text = "Selected Item is " +ClassType.Name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan. That really worked well. Isssue was knowing which class to cast it to as i had RootCategories class and Categories